# Configuration-files in a Greasemonkey script

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey, configuration-files

From what I understood, it is not possible to read files using Greasemonkey. I need to define lot of static configuration files, and it seems completely messy to include those directly in the user script.

So, what is the best way to store and retrieve that data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [it is not possible, by design, to read local files](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Security_Hole_.233:_Local_File_Access).

If your files are all a page or so of text, and don't change that often, go ahead and use [`GM_getResourceText()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceText), per Dr.Molle's answer.

If your files are large, or change rapidly, then host them on a server and use [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) to read back the file you need, at runtime.  See item 2, below.

---

1. Using `GM_getResourceText()` is the easiest and fastest way to proceed.  And, if the config files are reasonably sized (say less than 1K on average), this method will probably be faster than methods that rely on Ajax -- even with 150 (!!!) files.

   Drawback: You will have to bookmark an [awkward path](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox#Navigating_to_the_profile_folder) and remember it, when you want to edit a config file. (EG: `C:\Documents and Settings\<Windows login/user name>\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<profile folder>\gm_scripts\YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME\` )
2. If you really can't -- or don't want to -- use a bunch of relatively static files, the best choice is to host the config files on your server and have `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` read the needed file when the script runs.

   If you do not have your own server, then you can host the files someplace like [Google Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/).
3. Using [`GM_getValue()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue) or using [globalStorage or local storage](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Using_globalStorage) can all be very fast and efficient about ***getting*** your config file data (and only the data you want).  But, ***storing*** the data can be a major pain unless you write your own tools to do so (also a pain, but [others have done it](http://userscripts.org/guides/11)).
4. Using [`@require`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require) offers no advantage over `GM_getResourceText()` unless your config files are really valid JavaScript code.  And, this method will require you to uninstall and then reinstall your script every time the name of an include file changes -- or if you add or delete files.
   Not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You can load a ressource: http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getResourceText

Comment: Ressource stays on the local hard drive after the end of the session? Do you think loading 150 files this way is likely to slow down my script? There is no way of being selective and only load the appropriate config file?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can load it automatically using [@require](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40require)

Comment: Can I store all the paths to config files in an array, and make a loop of @require ? ( I have about 150 config files, so i don't want  to make the script lag,especially since only one file is required at the loading of the script)

Comment: well, if only 1 file is required, then you could retrieve that file dynamically on demand and put it in cache (GM_xmlhttpRequest and GM_setValue)